# How can I make this javascript function to allow more than 1 value to be entered into a input box with separated by a space?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the this html and javascript code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-id="0101">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      body {
        padding: 1rem;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .fb {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
      }
      div>button {
        width: 9%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        background: lightgray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fb">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
      <button>3</button>
      <button>4</button>
      <button>5</button>
      <button>6</button>
      <button>7</button>
      <button>8</button>
      <button>9</button>
      <button>10</button>
    </div>
    <p><input> <input></p>
    <p><button class="action-button">Colour by numbers</button></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

javaScript:

```
function colourByNumbers() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
    colour = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
    buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[inputs - 1]

    buttons.style.background = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
}
document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')[0].addEventListener("click", colourByNumbers);
```

what it does it you enter a number in and enter a color. the box with the entered number will change its background to the color entered like this:

[image: With a single number]

I'm stuck on how to make the function take in more than 1 input e.g:

[image: With multiple numbers]

so I enter in 2 numbers separated by a space(4 and 7) and their boxes both turn red

I've included a jsfiddle incase anyone wants to test the code themselves. Any help appreciated!
https://jsfiddle.net/waxhtekj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that the input is just a string.  Just use the split function to get get each value

```js
function colourByNumbers() {
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
    inputs = input.split(" ")    
    colour = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
    
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){    
       buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[inputs[i] - 1]
       buttons.style.background = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')[0].addEventListener("click", colourByNumbers);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-id="0101">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      body {
        padding: 1rem;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .fb {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
      }
      div>button {
        width: 9%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        background: lightgray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fb">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
      <button>3</button>
      <button>4</button>
      <button>5</button>
      <button>6</button>
      <button>7</button>
      <button>8</button>
      <button>9</button>
      <button>10</button>
    </div>
    <p><input> <input></p>
    <p><button class="action-button">Colour by numbers</button></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is change your function so that instead of just taking the value from the `buttons` input and using it, run a `String.prototype.split` on it and use a loop. Your JavaScript would look something like this:

```js
function colourByNumbers() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value.split(" ")
    colours = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value

    for (const input of inputs) {
         document.getElementsByTagName('button')[input - 1].style.background = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')[0].addEventListener("click", colourByNumbers);
```

Your JavaScript and HTML are also slightly malformed. For your HTML, you shouldn't use a plain `<input>`. Instead, specify the required attributes for your input tag like so: `<input type="text" />`. Also note the `/>`, which means to close the tag without content.

For your JavaScript, you a few problems. The first thing is how you are selecting your elements. Since you are only getting one element, use `document.getElementByClassName`, with `Element` instead of `Elements` to only get one element. That also removes the need for the `[0]`.

Next you have the function variables. You are not declaring proper variables, use a `const` in front of the definition. For settings the background, you already have selected the value, so you do not need to do it again.

Refactored JS Code:

```js
function colourByNumbers() {
    const inputs = document.getElementByTagName('input')[0].value.split(" ")
    const colour = document.getElementByTagName('input').value

    for (const input of inputs) {
         document.getElementsByTagName('button')[input - 1].style.background = colour;
    }
}
document.getElementByClassName('action-button').addEventListener("click", colourByNumbers);
```